# Validation for two fields on a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I was wondering if anyone could please need help me validate my form. 
The two fields that need validation are house number and postcode
I need to make the house number only two numbers
and the postcode only 5 characters.

I've used a pattern attribute and was wondering if I can display the message on more than one field.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  <label>Address</label>
 <br>
  <input name="address" type="text" placeholder="House Number" pattern="[0-9]{2}">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="address2" type="text" placeholder="Street Name">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="city" type="text" placeholder="City/Town">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}">
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Plant Type</label>
 <br>
 <select name="plant">
 <option value="tree">TREE</option>
 <option value="shrub">SHRUB</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Description</label>
 <br>
  <textarea input name="description">
  </textarea>
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Rating</label>
 <br>
<div class="rating"> 
<input id="star1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
<label for="star1" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

 
<input id="star2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
<label for="star2" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label> 
 
<input id="star3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
<label for="star3" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

<input id="star4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
<label for="star4" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

<input id="star5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
<label for="star5" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try regular expression 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in detail?

Comment: _“I need to make the house number only two numbers”_ - to which Sherlock Holmes just replied, _Don’t be a moron, Watson - and remember that we live at 221B Baker Street._

Comment: I want to be able to display a message for both input fields It only shows one at a time when I use html validation..

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can can do it using a html attribute maxlength = "2"

For Example

```html
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  <label>Address</label>
 <br>
  <input name="address" type="text" placeholder="House Number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" maxlength="2">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="address2" type="text" placeholder="Street Name">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="city" type="text" placeholder="City/Town">
 <br>
 <br>
  <input name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5">
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Plant Type</label>
 <br>
 <select name="plant">
 <option value="tree">TREE</option>
 <option value="shrub">SHRUB</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Description</label>
 <br>
  <textarea input name="description">
  </textarea>
 <br>
 <br>
  <label>Rating</label>
 <br>
<div class="rating"> 
<input id="star1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
<label for="star1" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

 
<input id="star2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
<label for="star2" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label> 
 
<input id="star3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
<label for="star3" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

<input id="star4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
<label for="star4" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>

<input id="star5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
<label for="star5" aria-hidden="true">
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</label>
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```